# Gutenberg not all editor text translated

Tags: translation, block-editor

I just upgraded to wordpress 5.0 and not all text in Gutenberg is translated to my website's language German and stays in English.

I already tried disabling all my plugins and switched to default theme, but that did not help. Also reinstalling wordpress and manually updating the language files was not helping.

Only when I enable the Gutenberg development plugin the text is translated, but am I supposed to enable the plugin after upgrading to wordpress 5?
[image: translation image]

Comment: In case you have a non-default folder setup this might be a bug in Core. See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/45528 for details.